# Nuget crashing visual studio 2019

Tags: nuget, visual-studio-2019

I have a ASP.NET framework MVC project that i've migrated from VS2017.  I've noticed that any nuget operation (new package, package update), done through either the UI or the package manager console will cause VS2019 to quit and restart on it's own.

- I've tried running VS2019 as admin like some have suggested, no luck.
- If I create a blank project, nuget works and doesn't crash Visual studio

does anyone have any guidance on troubleshooting this?

Comment: Did you check event log for any errors?

Comment: Hi friend, any update for this issue?

Answer (score 3):

Having checked many similar issues,but it's hard to locate the real cause since I can't reproduce the issue in my side.

Hope tips below can help resolve it:

1.In VS2019, Go to Tools -> NuGet Package Manager -> Package Manager Settings to Clear All NuGet Cache(s)

2.Open Developer Command Prompt for VS2019, enter `devenv /Safemode` to run VS in [safe mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/safemode-devenv-exe?view=vs-2019) (To check if some extension could be the cause)

3.Try a VS repair with Visual Studio installer

Answer (score 1):

If restoring also crashes VS (would happen automatically when using SDK-style projects, or you can right click the solution and select restore from the context menu), then there's a reasonable chance that one of your nuget.config files is invalid and we're crashing instead of giving a good error message. We rewrote the settings code around 4.7 or 4.8 I think, which caused some different behaviours in error cases. If VS crashes on restore, then you could try downloading the latest nuget.exe from nuget.org/downloads, and run `nuget restore` on the command line. it should crash as well, and maybe the error message will be helpful.

However, my suggestion as someone on the NuGet team is to use the "report a problem" tool, in particular use the feature to record while reproducing the error. This will record some extra information that my team can use to try to better figure out why we crashed instead of showing an error. Stack Overflow isn't an official support channel, so we can't help you here, but I would like to know what caused the crash so we can prevent it, even if you figure out how to prevent it in your case.

Answer (score 0):

For me solved updating VS 2019 community.
[image]

Comment: Do you know what version you upgraded from, and what version you upgraded to? That might help future readers isolate their issue if it is, in fact, a bug or compatibility issue with a specific version of Visual Studio.

Comment: Upgraded to 16.8.2, i don't remmember the version that i was facing the problem.